# jQuery Syntax - Getting a class starting with certain characters

Tags: jquery, syntax, jquery-selectors

I am trying to get part of a class of a div as a variable.

For example i have a div like so

```
<div class="menu-link scrollto-1">Home</div>
```

I also have javascript that runs when this element is clicked (The other 2 variables being passed are of no consequence to this so i have removed them for readability.

```
$(".menu-link").click(function() {
  var scroll = $(this).hasClass("scrollto-");
  alert (scroll);
  tabChange(menuTab,page, scroll);
});
```

What i need to do is:

- Get the class "scrollto-1"
- Alter this into "1" as a variable
- Pass this number to the function tabChange

I am a bit stumped how to achieve this (as there is 2 classes not just the 1) and i am unsure how to proceed. Any advice is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why not instead use the `index` of the `div` to pass to your function? Or even, pass the `div` itself to the function? This will make your classes more semantic and save a lot of headaches.

Comment: I'm not going to put this as an answer since it may be out of subject. But why not use the [data](http://api.jquery.com/data/) function of jQuery and store the variable in it. I do not believe using classes is a good idea, that's not their job.

Comment: I never knew about the data function.In this case im going to use classes as i cant learn how to use something new in a short deadline. But thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regular expression match to get the number from the `className` property:

```
$(".menu-link").click(function() {
  var scroll = this.className.match(/scrollto-(\d+)/)[1];
  alert (scroll);
  tabChange(menuTab,page, scroll);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd better put that into a data attribute

```
<div class="menu-link scrollto-1" data-scroll="1">Home</div>

$(".menu-link").click(function() {
  var scroll = $(this).data("scroll");
  alert (scroll);
  tabChange(menuTab,page, scroll);
});
```

or if you want to reuse the class as is :

```
<div class="menu-link scrollto-1" data-scroll="scrollto-1">Home</div>

$(".menu-link").click(function() {
  var scroll = $(this).data("scroll").replace("scrollto-", "");
  alert (scroll);
  tabChange(menuTab,page, scroll);
});
```

if you can't change the html:

```
$(".menu-link").click(function() {
  var cls = $(this).attr("class");
  var idx = cls.indexOf("scrollto-");
  var scroll = cls.substring(idx+9);
  tabChange(menuTab,page, scroll);
});
```